# NestedScrollView Crash Android

Tags: android

Trying to get back coding in android. Why do my program crash when I add another TextView to my XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_comp_analysis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.oscarorellana.physicscalaculators.Math.CompAnalysis">


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Enter a complex number below"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST"
            />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The XML file is my content file in one of my Android Activities. Probably really basic, but I can't find the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NestedScrollView` should have only one direct `child`. Add a new `Linear/Relative` layout as a container or `TextViews`.

**Try this:**

```
<NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
         <TextView>
         <TextView>
    <LinearLayout>
<NestedScrollView>
```

**Update your XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_comp_analysis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.oscarorellana.physicscalaculators.Math.CompAnalysis">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Enter a complex number below"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: @Oscar Orellana If this answer works please mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code : You need to add **child under the scroll view** , Then only the scroll view will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.oscarorellana.physicscalaculators.Math.CompAnalysis"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_comp_analysis">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Enter a complex number below"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_comp_analysis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.oscarorellana.physicscalaculators.Math.CompAnalysis">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Enter a complex number below"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```